# Can't sync photos from Windows to iPhone since iOS 6

Tags: itunes, iphone

Since the update to iOS 6, my iPhone (or iTunes) does not copy the photos I have on my Windows system to the iPhone.

The update to iOS 6.0.1 doesn't seem to have helped.

I have removed all photos from both the iPhone and the sync area on the Windows system, but when I return the photos to the sync area, nothing gets copied to the iPhone.

How can I get my photo sync to work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I got it working again.  Something in the following ritual did the trick:

- remove all photos and videos from the sync directory on the Windows system
- sync
- empty out the directories on the iPhone visible through the windows explorer
- remove all photos and videos from the iPhone
- sync
- recreate the sync directory on the Windows system with all the directories and photos (except the "Thumbnails" folder) as you want them
- go back into iTunes while the iPhone is connected, note that the "sync photos" checkboxk is cleaerd, re-check and verify that iTunes is looking at the correct sync directory
- sync

...and the photos are there.  I don't know which chicken-wave was the one which actually fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use other software like [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). If you can't be waiting, use iCloud to sync `%HOME%\Pictures\iCloud Photos\My Photo Stream` and copy out.